# How to get more information about "Error loading extension"?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

How do I get more information why a specific extension is not working and showing me "Error loading extension" when trying to enable it?

[image]

Comment: The new answer by @Cibes is a better alternative imo, you might want to consider accepting that instead.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Run

```
sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

and look for errors associated with the extension while trying to enable it. Alternatively you can use `grep` to filter logs by extension name:

```
sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell | grep 'system-monitor'
```

Also sometimes an extension works alright if you just manually add your GNOME shell version (which is not officially supported by the extension) to the extension's `metadata.json` file.
To do that (if you have installed the extension not as the root) go to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and look for the directory associated with the extension. Open it and you should find a `metadata.json` file inside. Open the file, add your GNOME shell version under the `"shell-version":` section and save the file. Relogin and if you're lucky the extension may start working.

Comment: This can contain a ton of log output, most of which probably doesn't relate to the error.

Comment: @Cerin "and look for errors *associated with the extension while trying to enable it*." Timestamps would be useful.

Comment: instead of "look for errors" you can use `grep`, e.g.: `sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell | grep 'system-monitor'` to look for errors from `system-monitor` extension

Answer (score 32):

You can see details of GNOME extensions, including errors, using GNOME's [Looking Glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass) tool:

1. press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `lg`, then <kbd>Return</kbd>.
2. go to the "Extensions" section
3. search the relevant extension and click on "Show Errors" for it

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. Now why could not Tweak Tools show those same error messages when clicking on what currently is a useless error  icon? That is a rhetorical question; no answer expected.

Comment: And how do you close it when it's stolen the focus and has no x icon?  You google on a different computer, then press Escape.

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu running inside of Docker.

Comment: Wow! Watching the Looking Glass apearing from nowhere reminded me from my early days in TI, when there was a unkown world to explore and everything was a nice surprise! Thank you for that.