# Dash-to-dock turns off whenever I turn my monitor off in Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME 3.28.4), only reboot turns it back on

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-dash, dash-to-dock

When I look at it in GNOME-tweak, it just gives me the unhelpful error message "Error loading extension". Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Related: [How to get more information about “Error loading extension”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1006499/480481)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a DtD bug.

Assuming that you've got the latest version of DtD, try this:

- open a `Files` window, and hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> keys to show hidden files/folders
- open the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` folder
- identify the DtD GNOME Shell extension folder by its name
- drag that folder out to the Desktop (or other open folder)
- restart GNOME Shell with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- move the DtD folder, from the Desktop (or previous open folder), back into its original folder
- restart the GNOME Shell again
- see if DtD works again

Comment: That seemed to fix it, but do I have to do that every time I restart my monitor?

Comment: @lightspectra Does `Tweaks` still show the "error loading extension" error? Then no, you should only have to do this once. It's a DtD bug.

Comment: The error is continuing to happen every time my monitor turns off.

Comment: @lightspectra  Does `Tweaks` still show an error loading DtD?

Comment: @lightspectra At https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/ someone suggests removing the standard Ubuntu docs extension and restarting GNOME Shell. DtD is buggy.

Comment: Tried it. Error is still occurring. At this point I'm just going to bind "gnome-shell -r" to a hotkey and deal with having to press it every time I turn my monitor on lol

Comment: Hey I have the same problem, did u find a workaround