# Colour filters other than red (maybe a cheap alternative to precision tinted lenses)

Tags: accessibility, color-management

Is this possible? Is there software to have a magenta or turquoise color filter, for example?

( It's an accessibility issue, relevant to irlen syndrome: I see extra shapes around letters and certain colour filters can help reduce them. You can get prescribed specialist tinted glasses, but when I get those they will be prescription and I don't need my prescription for things that are close up, like my computer screen.

Of course the redlight colour filter in "Displays" that's installed by default is useful, but it's not the optimal colour for me I find. Using Ubuntu 20.04

There is an android app called "tintvision" That does this for phones)
[image: a physical plastic version of these overlays.]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Do you know if you're using X or Wayland? If it's X, then you may be able to do something like this: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --gamma 1.5:1:1` (be sure to replace the `HDMI-1` bit with your actual display, and the `1.5` red value with something closer to what you want) 

Comment: Ubuntu 20.0, I assume it's xorg. How do I find out the name of my display? It's the laptop screen.

Comment: I found something, presumably anyone who red/orange works for can use the default, well I found something for people who blue works for: Go to settings, and then colour. There should be an option to "add profile" (it's not always there, not sure what that depends on) well, once I could add a profile, I saw one of the profiles was called "test profile - blue". So now I have a handy blue filter! Not a solution for everyone,just people who blue helps

Comment: In Compiz there's a built-in option "Color filter" which has several filters predefined (like blueish-filter, sepia, protanopia, grayscale etc.) Apparently there is a possibility to add own filters, but you have to create them somehow (I don't know exacly how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search and found [ColorTint](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1789/colortint/), a gnome shell extension that tints desktop colors. It seems to do exactly what you are looking for, and claims to "help with dyslexia, visual stress, scopic sensitivity, and related conditions" by changing the colors of your desktop. It lets you choose the exact color in RGB and opacity in the settings.

If you are unfamiliar with Gnome Shell extensions, see [this article from LinuxHint](https://linuxhint.com/installing_gnome_extensions_ubuntu/) on how to install them.

Comment: maybe file an issue on their github page (linked in the shell extensions page). also, what kind of error are you getting? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006499/how-to-get-more-information-about-error-loading-extension , also maybe try hitting alt-f2 and then typing `r` to reload the shell (sometimes fixes errors)

Comment: yes! That must have been it. when went the long way round and did this https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2017/11/how-to-install-manually-gnome-shell-extension.html I have it installed, turned on through gnome-tweak, and i can change the settings using an icon on the panel. Fantastic! thank very very much!

Comment: go here to get the file if you still need to install it manually, people of the future: https://github.com/MattByName/color-tint

( also if all this is too hard, you might find it easier to find a firefox or chrome extension for color overlays )

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [eyesome](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome) which lets you set brightness and gamma. It has two configurations per monitor. One configuration for when the sun is rising and one for when the sun is setting.

> **Disclaimer:** I wrote eyesome.

Comment: That's looks cool but I don't think it does colour filters, does it? The only colours it does is colour temperature, as in, one colour filter, orange, turned up or down. If you check out the android app "colour filters" you can see the sort of thing I mean. It allows you to place an "overlay " on your phone screen in whatever colour you want. I've added a picture of the physical version to the original post