# When upgrading an Ubuntu Server instance with ubuntu-desktop-minimal package to 22.04, Dock disappears

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04, ubuntu-dock, taskbar

After upgrading an Ubuntu Server instance with the `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` package installed to 22.04, the Dock disappears and won't come back

Failed attempts to remedy this

- choosing to disable and then enable the Dock in the Settings doesn't work (this seems like it may be a bug as the options appear in the menu to do so, despite as discovered later, the Dock is disabled)
- attempting in Settings to move the position of the Dock to a different edge of the screen
- neither reinstalling, nor reconfiguring the package `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` appears to do anything
- though suggested [in a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/r30oog/the_task_bar_on_my_laptop_is_gone_and_i_dont_know/), calling `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/` doesn't appear to have any effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `lg` to bring up the "[Looking Glass](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108266/523028)" ([official docs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass)) tool shows that the Dock is disabled (though confusingly offers no way to enable it, nor information as to why it was disabled)
Looking Glass can then (again, confusingly) be quit by going to the Evaluator panel and pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>

With this knowledge, `gnome-extensions` can be used to enable the Dock again

```shell
gnome-extensions list  # show Extension package names
gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: as a casual note a little later, I may have been using a nonstandard dock and forgot because it felt much more natural - maybe the experience will improve in future versions